# I want to zoom to a circle directly in d3js without clicking or double clicking it but programmatically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, selection

After many attempts unable to zoom in d3js. 
I have the following code which is properly creating SVG and HTML elements with correct values and ids. 
What's wrong with **zoomTo3rdCircle()** ? I want that when a user clicks a button "Zoom To Third Circle" then that circle should be zoomed and bring to center of the svg. But it seems the code is not doing anything, it is not even giving any error. I think so I am missing something very small but critical.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Zoom & Pan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <svg width=700 height=700> </svg>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = 700, height = 700;

        var data = [
            { "id": "firstcircle", "r": 10, "cx": 100, "cy": 150 },
            { "id": "secondcircle", "r": 30, "cx": 200, "cy": 150 },
            { "id": "thirdcircle", "r": 15, "cx": 300, "cy": 150 }

        ];
        var svg = d3.select("body").select("svg")
            .call(
                d3.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([1, 3])
                    .on("zoom", zoom)
            );

        const g = svg.append("g");

        g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.interpolateRainbow(i / 3))
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; });

        function zoom() {
            g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        }

        var zoomer = d3.zoom();
        function zoomTo3rdCircle() {

            var thirdCircle = d3.select("#thirdcircle"); 
            thirdCircle.style("stroke", "blue");
            thirdCircle.style("fill", "yellow");

            x = thirdCircle.attr("cx");
            y = thirdCircle.attr("cy");

            g.transition().duration(1000).call(
                zoomer.transform,
                d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2, height / 2).scale(2.5).translate(x, y)
            );


        }



    </script>

<button onclick="zoomTo3rdCircle()">Zoom To Third Circle </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`var zoomer = d3.zoom()`

to

```
var zoomer = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        });
```

at least did some movement and zooming started to work. BUT it has sprouted another issue and that is after zoomed through button when I zoom-in or zoom-out using mouse, the WHOLE 'g' goes back to its previous position and starts zooming from there. Which is weird and confuses the user.

> *By the way I still don't know how to zoom in such a way that FOCUS goes to 3rd Circle; and after that when user zooms through mouse-wheel
>   it zooms from current position instead of previous position*

I thought to answer my question by updating the progress made.